# Using a button in parent component to call function in child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a modal functional component which has a child class component acting as a form input. My submit button is in the modal, but I need to use information that I store in the child's states to submit my query using my function. How can I call this function in the child class component from the parent's submit button?

Parent functional component:

```
function AddGearModal() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  return (
    <Container>
      <Modal
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
        onOpen={() => setOpen(true)}
        open={open}
        trigger={
          <Button icon>
            <Icon name="plus" />
          </Button>
        }
      >
        <Modal.Header>Add New Gear</Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Content>
          <AddGearForm />
        </Modal.Content>
        <Modal.Actions>
          <Button color="black" onClick={() => setOpen(false)}>
            Nope
          </Button>
          //this button should call handleSubmit() in child component
          <Button
            content="Add Gear"
            labelPosition="right"
            icon="checkmark"
            onClick={() => setOpen(false)}
            positive
          />
        </Modal.Actions>
      </Modal>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Child class component:

```
class AddGearForm extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    level: "1",
    available: "1",
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
      //I want to call this from parent component
  };

  //any changes to form inputs will set their corresponding state
  handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
    console.log("State changed: ", name, value);
  };

  render() {
    const { name, level, available } = this.state;
    const levelOptions = [
      { key: "1", value: "1", text: "Film 1" },
      { key: "2", value: "2", text: "Film 2" },
      { key: "3", value: "3", text: "Film 3" },
      { key: "4", value: "4", text: "Film 4" },
    ];
    const availableOptions = [
      { key: "1", value: "1", text: "Yes" },
      { key: "0", value: "0", text: "No" },
    ];
    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Field>
          <Form.Input
            label="Gear Name"
            placeholder="Name"
            name="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </Form.Field>
        <Form.Group widths="equal">
          <Form.Field
            control={Select}
            name="level"
            value={level}
            options={levelOptions}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <Form.Field
            control={Select}
            name="available"
            value={available}
            options={availableOptions}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to read up on passing down a dispatch using the useReducer() hook, but I'm having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: also if anyone's confused on my tags, they are from semantic-ui-react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is referred to as "lifting state" to a parent. *Ideally* you don't want to store state in two places, so it may make sense to pass the state back down to the child as a prop vs storing the state there. I'll give you a simplified example.

```
const Parent = () => {
    // store the state here
    const [state, setState] = useState(null)

    // handler that you pass into child and updates state
    const handleChange = (/* params */) => setState(/* set new value */) 
    
    // pass state & handler to child
    return <Child value={state} onChange={handleChange} />
}

// pass the value & handler to child
const Child = ({ value, onChange }) => {
    // pass the new value to the parent (lifting state)
    return <Form.Field onChange={onChange} />
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. However, I tried to implement it, however now it seems to be that the onChange is not being called. I placed a console.log inside the handleChange handler, and it doesn't show on console. Furthermore, I can't seem to type anything in the form field.

Comment: Oh nevermind! I passed handleChange instead of onChange to my child. Silly mistake

Comment: @LukeLewis if this helped ya, upvote and accept the answer, pls.

Comment: done! My reputation is still low so the upvote isn’t visible unfortunately.

Comment: Np. Glad I could help.